# Can I use R.Net without installing R

Tags: c#, r, r.net

I am building an application within C# and I want to use some of the R libraries within this application. I am using R.Net to do this.

However, I will deploy this software to users that may not have R downloaded on there computers. Is there any way that I can use the R dll so that the users can run my application without having to install R onto there machines?

Many thanks

Comment: As per the docs: On Windows, R.NET requires .NET Framework 4.5.2 and an access to the native R libraries installed with the R environment. R needs not necessarily be installed as a software on the executing machine, so long as DLL files are accessible. On Linux and MacOS, Mono is required, as well as an access to the native R libraries.

Comment: Are the relevant DLL files just R.dll along with any of the packages used?

Comment: AFAIK you just need the dll included with the nuget package and that's it

Answer (score 2):

While this question is rather old, maybe this elaboration on Hackerman's answer will still help someone:

You do not have to have R installed properly on your computer and you also do not have to have any registry entries for R if you want to use R.NET. However, R.NET still needs to access the native DLLs found in ...\R\bin\i386 and the contents of ...\R\library.

Assuming your R files are located at C:\Program Files, setting the paths to ...\R\bin\i386 and ...\R\library works as follows:

```
REngine.SetEnvironmentVariables(@"C:\Program Files\R\bin\i386", @"C:\Program Files\R");
```

You can then set up an REngine using:

```
REngine engine = REngine.GetInstance();
```

This works using R.NET v1.7 and R v3.4.2 (32bit).