# How to save a plot generated via R.NET to a file on disk?

Tags: c#, r, r.net

I am using R.NET to generate plots (using `ggplot`) and I want to save these graphs in PNG format on disk. Whenever I call `engine.Evaluate("ggsave('C:\path\to\file.png', myPlot)")` the program abruptly aborts with exit code 2 without anything being written to disk; no error is displayed when this happens. It is also not possible to write the plot to a file using `png()` or `pdf()`. This problem is not specific to `ggplot`, however - I also cannot store plots generated via the native `plot` function.

I could narrow down the problem to the line containing either `ggsave()` or `png()`/`pdf()`: when this line is executed, the program aborts. Since I can actually see the plots generated by both, `ggplot()` and `plot()`, the plotting itself does not seem to be the issue.

You should be able to recreate what I described using the following C# code:

```
using RDotNet;

namespace Test {
  class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      REngine.SetEnvironmentVariables();
      REngine engine = REngine.GetInstance();

      engine.Evaluate("png('D:\\Test.png')");
      engine.Evaluate("plot(rnorm(1000))");
      engine.Evaluate("dev.off()");  
    }
  }
}
```

[Apparently, this code should work without any issues](https://coders-corner.net/2015/11/22/use-r-in-c-create-a-data-plot-and-save-it-as-png/).

When running

```
png('D:\\Test.png')
plot(rnorm(1000))
dev.off()
```

in R, a plot is generated and saved to Test.png successfully.

I am using .NET Framework 4.6.1, R.NET 1.7.0, and R 3.4.2. R is not installed on my computer and registry entries have not been created for R - I am just using the R DLLs as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55450302/11289327).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that you cannot have backslashes as you mention in your answer. Although forward slashes solve your problem as well, I think it might help in the future if I explain the other solution.

### You have to escape your backslash twice.

Once for C#, once for R.

Calling Evaluate like this

```
engine.Evaluate("png('D:\\Test.png')");
```

will call the `R` engine with the string: `"png('D:\\Test.png')"`, which, if you evaluate it is just: *png('D:\Test.png')*. If you typed that into R you'd get an error as well.

If you want to run the R command `png('D:\\Test.png')`, **you have to escape that string**, which has two backslashes after escaping both **it becomes: `"png('D:\\\\Test.png')"`**.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this clarification! I  spent hours trying to figure out why the plots wouldn't be saved - and I never would have guessed that I'd have to use four backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, you cannot have backslashes in the image file's path. If you want to write an image to a file on disk, you have to use forwardslashes, e.g. instead of

```
engine.Evaluate("png('D:\\Test.png')");
```

use

```
engine.Evaluate("png('D:/Test.png')");
```

Maybe this is still helpful for someone else.